# calling magento web service from android client using kSoap2

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, xmlpullparser

i am trying to access a magento web service from a android client.which should return a session id.i hav already done this uing java client using apache and am successful in calling the method.
How ever i am getting xmlpullparser exception when trying with android client as:
10-24 15:25:44.409: WARN/System.err(277): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:327 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44ee2268)

well this is my wsdl file from which i am trying to access login method:[image: wsdl]

my java code:

```
public class DeviceClientActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private static final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "login";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerAction";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log
    .d("WS",
          "--------------------- Webservice Part Begins ---------------------");  
Log.d("WS", "1. SoapObject Construction");  
SoapObject objsoap=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

objsoap.addProperty("username", "alokxxxx");
  objsoap.addProperty("apiKey", "xxxxxx");
  Log.d("WS", "Construction of SOAP Object End !!!");

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
      SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
Log.d("WS", "2. Envelop Created");    
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(objsoap);
Log.d("WS", "3. Request Into Envelop");
AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
httpTransport.debug = true; 
Log.d("WS", "5. Transport Level to True");
try {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

//**error here WARN/System.err(277): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:327 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44ee2268)**

```
Log.d("WS", "6. httpTransport.call");
    if (envelope != null) 
    {
       SoapObject loresponse = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
       SoapObject logObject = (SoapObject)loresponse.getProperty("sessionId");           
       Log.d("WS", "logObject: "+logObject);                      
    } 
    else 
    {
       Log.d("WS", "Response Envelop Error");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

}

log for your help:
DEBUG/WS(333): --------------------- Webservice Part Begins ---------------------
10-29 15:38:33.643: DEBUG/WS(333): 1. SoapObject Construction
10-29 15:38:33.673: DEBUG/WS(333): Construction of SOAP Object End !!!
10-29 15:38:33.673: DEBUG/WS(333): 2. Envelop Created 
10-29 15:38:33.673: DEBUG/WS(333): 3. Request Into Envelop
10-29 15:38:33.683: DEBUG/WS(333): 5. Transport Level to Trueorg.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport@44eeb200
10-29 15:38:33.683: DEBUG/Try(333): inside try block
10-29 15:38:34.903: WARN/System.err(333): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:327 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44efbe90)
any suggestion?
thanks.

Comment: If you have got the solutions then please help me ...I am facing the same problem...Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i got the login to work.
the trick is not to put the ?wsdl on the url

```
public boolean login()  
    {
        try
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/","login");
            request.addProperty("username",apiuid.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("apiKey",apipwd.getText().toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
            envelope.dotNet=false;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(apiurl.getText().toString());
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/login", envelope);
            String result =(String)envelope.getResponse();
            String URL = new String();
            URL=apiurl.getText().toString();
            Editor e = userDetails.edit();
                e.putString("url", URL);
                e.putString("uid", apiuid.getText().toString());
                e.putString("pwd", apipwd.getText().toString());
                e.putString("lastsession", result);
                e.commit();
               return true;
        } catch(IOException e)
             {alertbox("IO error",e.getMessage());return false;}
          catch(XmlPullParserException e)
             {alertbox("xml error",e.getMessage());return false;}
          catch(Exception e)
             {alertbox("error",e.getMessage());return false;}     
    }
```